# Does ruby calculate floats wrong?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Whats wrong here? (ruby version: 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.0.0]

```
x = 523.8
w = 46.9
xm = x + w
assert_equal w, (xm - x) # FAILS with: <46.9> expected but was <46.89999999999998>
```

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @Vache: unfortunately this site is for programmers, not computer scientists, and Goldberg's paper rather more complex and detailed than people can be expected to accept as an answer to a simple question.

Comment: Which is why I posted this as a comment and not an answer. :)

Comment: "programmers, not computer scientists" - they ought to be synonymous, enough to be able to understand that article and floating point numbers.

Comment: This has to be a duplicate question.

Comment: @Michael Borgward: I am neither a programmer nor a computer scientist, I am just a dentist with a hobby, and yet I had no problem understanding the Goldberg article. I think a "programmer" (as opposed to a "computer scientist") should be able to read it, with some effort.

Comment: @duffymo: in practice they are not synonymous at all. Programmers generally don't need to read scientific papers to do their work, and computer scientists generally don't need to write user-friendly and maintainable software to do theirs.

Comment: @Rudy: with some effort perhaps, but it would take several hours, and thus not a reasonable answer to this kind of question.

Comment: I think it is, since it explains what people should know about floating point. That can prevent a lot of additional questions. Some things can't be explained in a few sentences.

Answer (score 10):

From [The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/):

> **Why don’t my numbers, like 0.1 + 0.2 add up to a nice round 0.3, and
>   instead I get a weird result like 0.30000000000000004?**
>
> Because internally, computers use a format (binary floating-point)
>   that cannot accurately represent a number like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.
>
> When the code is compiled or interpreted, your “0.1” is already
>   rounded to the nearest number in that format, which results in a small
>   rounding error even before the calculation happens.

Read the linked-to site for details and ways to get around this.

Comment: -1 for gaining rep on a duplicate question.

Answer (score 6):

This is perfectly normal; it is a fact about the lower-level concept of floating point arithmetic rather than Ruby and therefore can occur in any language.

Floating point arithmetic is not exact. Equality should be replaced with closeness along the lines of  `assert((xm-x).abs < epsilon)`, where `epsilon` is some small number like `0.01`.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).  It describes the way binary representation of floating point numbers work in every language, not just Ruby.

Comment: Is the (sigh) necessary?

Comment: It is you who brings in "reputation" - reputation alone does not mean anything at all. You are being presumptuous in your reply. Others manage without that attitude and provide better answers - see the one above your reply. Unlike you I find the question perfectly well suited and well deserving for an answer. If you have a problem answering without an attitude, perhaps don't answer at all? I am not the one to attack newcomers with a "sigh". Why are you such a drama queen? If there is anyone trolling then it is you - from a technical point of view, there is no need for "sigh" emoting.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: **No**.

(Other answers tell you why, but you didn't ask that. :p)